# For what reason i can't retrieve element by ID once climbed on his parent?

Tags: javascript, html

in html i've a code like this

```
<body>
  <script src="debug.js"></script>   
  <button id="proof" onclick="debug('result:', this);">proof</button>
</body>
```

and in javascript:

```
function debug(msg, e) 
{

    var log = document.getElementById("debuglog");

    if (!log)// If no element with the id "debuglog" exists, create one.
    {
        log = document.createElement("div"); /
        log.id = "debuglog";
        log.innerHTML = "<h1>Debug Log</h1>"; 
        document.body.appendChild(log); 
   }


    var pre = document.createElement("pre");
    var text = document.createTextNode(msg + e.parentNode.getElementById("proof")); //<--PROBLEM HERE
    pre.appendChild(text);
    log.appendChild(pre); 
    }
}
```

Note that the code works if into the text node i write **msg + e.parentNode**, once i add **.getElementById("proof")**, no result is retrieved (i think that the script goes in error in runtime phase).

What i want to do is "navigate" throught the html elements, calling his parents and his childrens

Comment: what does e.parentNode.innerHTML returns? what is 'e' here?

Comment: ops, i forgot to post the function intitializer
function debug(msg, e), where e is the button element that calls the function

Comment: That doesn't change my answer :P

Comment: it retunrs the entire html body's code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the ID has to be a unique element on a page, you can simply access it by using document.getElementById('YOURID'). It is method of document so your script throws an error. If you want to implement something like this, you have to do it by a custom function:

```
function youShouldNotDoThis( element, id ) {
    var hit = null;
    if ( element.getAttribute('id') == id ) {
        return element;
    }
    for ( var i = 0, l = element.childNodes.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        if ( element.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1 ) {
            hit = youShouldNotDoThis( element.childNodes[i], id );
            if ( hit != null ) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return hit;
}
```

And in your script fragment:

```
var whyEver = youShouldNotDoThis(e.parentNode,'proof');
var text = document.createTextNode(msg + whyEver); //<--NO MORE PROBLEM HERE
```

And again, you should not do this by the Attribute ID, because ID should be unique, but you can easily change this function to scan for something different than ID.

Comment: yes i know that syntax, but i want to go up to the parent and return on the desired children (this is a thing that i do in actionscript 3)..
There exists another syntax for do that?

Comment: @AnnaLica parentNode.childNodes is an array containing the direct children of the parent Element.

Comment: tryied, but it's possibile to call childNodes by name?
I wrote:
---- e.parentNode.childNodes["proof"] --- but the result is "undefined"

Comment: @AnnaLica Do you mean the nodeName something like pre? You could use: parentNode.getElementsByTagName('pre'), returns also an array.

Comment: i don't mean tag.. Once that i've a child/node with ID "proof", i want to call it by id.
I know that is possible to use document.getElementById, but i want to do a different round, calling first the "e" parent and after calling one of his child by ID

Comment: @AnnaLica Updated my answer providing an example, hope this helps, even if I still don't get your point.

Comment: Lol, the function of your update is the same function I linked to. But good to have a copy here on SO should that one go down. I did a rewrite of that function without the errors and speeding it up using reverse while loop.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById` is a prototype of `document`, not a prototype of each and every element (inside the document).
So if you want to restrict `getElementById` to search children of a specific element instead of searching the entire document (in the same way one can do `getElementsByTagName` using a specific element as the parent) you'll need to add your own proto-type to all elements (but IE does not support prototyping on HTMLElement) or write your own function.

See [this page](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=38552) for some suggestions, but keep in mind, an Id should always be unique inside a page, so simply using `document.getElementById` that is built-in and optimized in the browser is still going to be faster.

**Update:**
Here is a rewrite of the function I linked to, without the errors and a faster reverse-while loop:

```
function GetChildById( dNode, id ) {
    var i, dResult = null;

    if ( dNode.getAttribute('id') === id ) { return dNode; }

    i=dNode.childNodes.length;
    while ( i-- ) {
        if ( dNode.childNodes[i].nodeType === 1 ) {
            dResult = GetChildById( dNode.childNodes[i], id );
            if ( dResult !== null )
                break;
        }
    }

    return dResult;
}
```

Usage: `GetChildById( node, 'id' )`

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SEpfQ/)

But like axel.michel said: don't do that, it's useless.

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edits for the typos. I thought this was needed. Feel free to rollback.

Comment: @Nivas, thank you for correcting that typo ! I'm also king of edit, hating typo's if I see them. But I'm not a 'native' speaker, so sometimes I must rely on spellcheck haha. Besides the thing I like here is that these sites are 'ours', we all moderate and help to create 'our' knowledge-base!